# Pearltrees doesn't work in Firefox, but works in Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

In Firefox, if it's the first time I visit Pearltrees, the Pearltrees progress bar goes until the end, then it stays a fully loaded bar and nothing else happens. If it's not, the Pearltrees progress bar starts fully loaded and nothing else happens. In Chrome, I can use Pearltrees normally. How to make Pearltrees work in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest Adobe Flash plugin available (and that you're not blocking flash with an extension) for Firefox. Pearltrees intro progress bar appears to work for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Pearltrees conflicts with BetterPrivacy, I think.